# SceneKit memory management issues

Tags: swift, memory-management, scenekit

So I am playing around with SceneKit (in Swift), and for pure fun, creating an endless runner style game. In the game scene, I have a character moving forward on the z-axis. I have setup a few objects that are repeatedly created when the last expires. Most of these objects are under a node hierarchy. So, I have attempted these two methods for memory management:

Method 1: I have an invisible plane. Only 'special' parent node bodies can collide with this plane. So when the parent node's physics body collides with it, I remove it from the parent, which in result the node removes all of its children.

Method 2: Again I have an invisible plane. Except in this method everything I would potentially like to remove, can and does collide with the invisible plane on it's own accord. So in plain, everything collides with the invisible plane and removes itself from it's parent.

Now. Everything runs and works well. Except when it comes to removing nodes from their parents, I see a noticeable jolt in the framerate or speed of the game. Just for a second or so. With method 1, the jolt happens once for every time a parent node collides with my invisible plane. With method 2, the jolts are continuous and framerate is continuously low and jumpy.

I would be interested in hearing knowledge on ways of achieving something like this smoothly!

A big thanks in advance.